# Which tessellating 4-polytope has the largest symmetry group?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, euclidean-geometry, tessellations

If we consider the set of all 4-polytopes which can tessellate four-dimensional space, which has the largest symmetry group?

The tesseract clearly tessellates four-dimensional space and its symmetry group has order $2 \times 8 \times 6 \times 4 = 384$. Can we beat this?

Comment: I believe 24-cell has more.